# request.getRequestDispatcher() called recursively

Tags: java, servlets

I've encountered a strange problem where my servlet doGet method will be run three times.

I tested this in Chrome and Firefox, and it's the same. I also deployed the project on another computer and used apache server to see if also does it when the site is live, but no change.

I use a switch in my doGet and a getParameter request to find the proper method to be run. I've shortened the switch to just two cases. But everytime the action is "create" It'll run the method three times.

I know this is very narrow, and I'd wish I were able to give you more information, but I do not know where to dig after it.

EDIT: The problem has been found. A request.getRequestDispatcher is causing it. Any help with this issue is very appreciated.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        // To see that it runs 3 times.
        System.out.println(action);

        switch (action) {
        case "create":
           this.create(request, response);
           break;
        default:
           this.greetGuest(request, response);
           break;
    }
}

protected void createEvent(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        request.setAttribute("AbstractUser", SessionUser);
        // Here's the problem. This part will cause the doGet to be called multiply times.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/view/Organisation/create.jsp").forward(
                request, response);     
    }

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        this.doGet(request, response);
    }


//html
<a href="eventHandler?action=create">Create</a>

//Configuration
@WebServlet(name = "eventHandler", urlPatterns = { "/eventHandler" }, loadOnStartup = 1)

//web.xml
   <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
            <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jsp/base.jspf</include-prelude>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
            <default-content-type>text/html</default-content-type>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
```

Comment: Servlets are configured to process requests matching URL patterns, so every time the browser makes a request matching the pattern, your servlet will be run. If you use something like Chrome Developer Tools to monitor web traffic, are multiple GET requests being made on this URL pattern? What pattern have you configured, anyhow?

Comment: @DavidS I can't see where specifically I have to look for the GET requests, I guess it's under networking?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Open Developer Tools on any tab(F12) and go to the Network tab. Choose "Preserve log" to prevent it from clearing the log when navigating to new URLs. Navigate to a new page and you should see a flood of requests, but fortunately on your JSP-based website you should only see a few. Note that this will only help you understand how your page and servlet _works_. For example, you may see that "Oh, in this case three GET requests are issued" and then you'll have to think about what that means for you.

Comment: But how is your servlet configured? it should be something like `@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})`.

Comment: @DavidS I added the servlet  configurations. Under networking I only see a eventHandler?action=create once. Method GET and 200 OK. I think it's just being called once then. In console I can now see it runs four times.

Comment: I can't explain why it's happening _four_ times, but I suspect this has something to do with your servlet mapping and your forwarding to `/WEB-INF/jsp/view/Organisation/create.jsp`. It seems like this Servet you've created it being used to handle more requests that you intended.

Comment: @DavidS I added the web.xml maybe that can give some more information. It's definetly the /WEB-INF/jsp/view/Organisation/create.jsp . I just tried to comment it out and now it runs just once. Is there another way to handle this? I still want to keep my "security" so that only servlet may redirect to some part of the website.